Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException certificate issue
When I debug my API (.NET 8) locally towards my local SQL Server (16.0.1000.6) using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 5.2.0 an exception gets thrown due to certificate issues.
Debugging through http / https options in visual studio gives me the following exception;

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

Debugging through docker gives me a slightly different error, yet I assume the underlying issue is the same;

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Certificate failed chain validation. Error(s): 'self-signed certificate, [Status: UntrustedRoot]
'.
Certificate name mismatch. The provided 'DataSource' or 'HostNameInCertificate' does not match the name in the certificate.

As of my understanding this is due to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient changing Encrypt=true by default.
Tried to follow the suggested solutions in this post: Entity Framework Core 7 connection certificate trust exception
This would involve adding Encrypt=false or TrustServerCertificate=True to my connectionstring (I didn't try the install valid certificate one)
Which means (if my understanding is correct) my connection string would look like one of the described 2 ways;
"Server=host.docker.internal, 1433;Database=***;User ID=***;Password=***;TrustServerCertificate=True"
or
"Server=host.docker.internal, 1433;Database=RaceEnduranceHub;User ID=***;Password=***;Encrypt=false
after that the connection string is used by AddDbbContextFactory like this;
services.AddDbContextFactory<EnduranceHubContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("default")).EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

Unfortunatly these two examples do not solve the exception and the exact same exception remains the same.

EF isn't a data access library or database driver. What matters is the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version. Also post the full exception text. An internal exception was caught means there's another exception in that text with additional information. It may complain about timeouts, SSL or something else

@PanagiotisKanavos I don't have this package installed at all Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. I just installed the package and will put an updated stack trace since I still get the same error

@DaleK it give me the reason why the error occurs indeed, but I don't know what the correct solution is to this error

@DaleK Either adding Encrypt=false OR TrustServerCertificate=True do not do the trick for me. My exception remains the same as mention in the supposed duplicate.

Then you must have done it wrong. Either way, your question details are now completely different to what you say you are doing... so no one can assist...

I'll try giving it a rewrite in a few to describe it in a more accurate manner.

@DaleK Does this give a more clear picture to what is happening? Let me know. Thank you

I suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/connection-string-syntax?view=sql-server-ver16
